# How to forecast billing for Azure Logic Apps with Enterprise Connectors?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a use case wherein I am trying to understand the estimated bill per month for a scenario which requires one of the enterprise connectors which can yield up to 400 million messages a day. Assuming there will be in all 4-5 added actions involving parsing, transforming and persisting the message, how to calculate the price of service per month?

Answer (score 3):

Well, your example broke the pricing calculator. It could not handle billions of executions on Actions executed, but I guess if you take the Actions executed price value times 5. [Pricing example calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?service=logic-apps#logic-apps202b37f2-fd2d-4117-87e5-66a2147f61fd)

Sounds like it will be cheaper to do this in another way or at the very least, not using an Enterprise Connector. What connector is it that you are planning to run even?

Have you looked at the prerequisites and **limitations** of the connector? Will it be able to handle 400 million executions per day?

[image: Pricing, much expensive]

Comment: Shouldn't the actions to execute be 5 instead of 400 million?

Comment: That is the count of how many times the action is executed. As you pay per execution and the 400 million enterprise connector is per day and 400 million * 5 actions for parsing(2 billion). That's for one day and then times 31 for a month. But sure if you only run the logic app one time per day where it executes the actions one time each and then does the 400 million enterprise connector executions.

Comment: I am considering not using LA for application integration given the steep charge. Considering to replace this with Event Hub.

Comment: i agree with you, logic apps are not designed for such high throughput, from my experience, your best bet servicebus/azure functions